# Converting mpfr or bigint datatype to fixed-point

Tags: c++, gmp, fixed-point, mpfr

I have a simple accounting program which uses bigint from GMP and MPFR for floats. Now I want to implement fixed point arithmatic through out the program for which i have defined my own class fixed<32,16> with suitable operations. What is the most efficient way to do this in order to avoid rewriting majority of the code.